# CentOS 7.2.1511 libvirt firewall configuration

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos7, libvirt, firewalld

I have a few CentOS7 setups in which I use iptables to forward ports from host to guests. Recently, i updated to 7.2.1511 and it seems libvirt insists firewalld to be active vs using iptables command directly.

Below is a XML configuration of my virtual network VMmaint.
`<network connections='11'>
<name>VMmaint</name>
<uuid>2d218af6-b374-41b3-8a7e-2de7a02e62a9</uuid>
<forward dev='em1' mode='nat'>
<nat>
<port start='1024' end='65535'/>
</nat>
<interface dev='em1'/>
</forward>
<bridge name='VMmaint' stp='on' delay='0'/>
<mac address='52:54:00:ab:82:15'/>
<ip address='192.168.100.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
<dhcp>
<range start='192.168.100.10' end='192.168.100.254'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:f7:df:11' ip='192.168.100.11'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:f1:bb:18' ip='192.168.100.12'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:cf:33:59' ip='192.168.100.13'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:57:e2:6a' ip='192.168.100.14'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:72:8e:ce' ip='192.168.100.15'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:25:3e:34' ip='192.168.100.16'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:8a:31:3e' ip='192.168.100.17'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:dd:5f:dd' ip='192.168.100.18'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:67:0b:fa' ip='192.168.100.19'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:0d:37:bd' ip='192.168.100.20'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:a5:7a:02' ip='192.168.100.21'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:e2:8d:94' ip='192.168.100.22'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:12:fb:15' ip='192.168.100.23'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:01:cb:98' ip='192.168.100.24'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:b0:d5:04' ip='192.168.100.25'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:6c:bf:9e' ip='192.168.100.26'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:d4:cc:5a' ip='192.168.100.27'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:6e:1d:8d' ip='192.168.100.28'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:aa:31:17' ip='192.168.100.29'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:42:d8:e5' ip='192.168.100.30'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:28:15:d5' ip='192.168.100.31'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:99:56:a1' ip='192.168.100.32'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:7a:e6:09' ip='192.168.100.33'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:2a:fe:67' ip='192.168.100.34'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:f1:95:37' ip='192.168.100.35'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:a9:4f:92' ip='192.168.100.36'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:ee:7d:40' ip='192.168.100.37'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:51:40:33' ip='192.168.100.38'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:b1:0c:6e' ip='192.168.100.39'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:2f:9f:ad' ip='192.168.100.40'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:c6:7e:1c' ip='192.168.100.41'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:6f:96:82' ip='192.168.100.42'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:e4:a8:b0' ip='192.168.100.43'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:4f:c6:97' ip='192.168.100.44'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:e2:1a:36' ip='192.168.100.45'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:bd:59:03' ip='192.168.100.46'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:f2:ca:f0' ip='192.168.100.47'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:f4:35:85' ip='192.168.100.48'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:c6:2f:84' ip='192.168.100.49'/>
<host mac='52:54:00:e7:74:a4' ip='192.168.100.50'/>
</dhcp>
</ip>
</network>`

However, as soon as the network is active, I see the following spewing out of /var/log/firewalld

`2016-03-18 14:07:00 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -w --table mangle --delete POSTROUTING --out-interface VMmaint --protocol udp --destination-port 68 --jump CHECKSUM --checksum-fill' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
2016-03-18 14:07:00 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -w --table filter --delete FORWARD --destination 192.168.100.0/24 --in-interface em1 --out-interface VMmaint --match conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED --jump ACCEPT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
2016-03-18 14:07:00 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -w --table filter --delete FORWARD --source 192.168.100.0/24 --in-interface VMmaint --out-interface em1 --jump ACCEPT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
2016-03-18 14:07:00 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -w --table filter --delete FORWARD --in-interface VMmaint --out-interface VMmaint --jump ACCEPT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
2016-03-18 14:07:00 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -w --table filter --delete FORWARD --out-interface VMmaint --jump REJECT' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
2016-03-18 14:07:00 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -w --table filter --delete FORWARD --in-interface VMmaint --jump REJECT' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
2016-03-18 14:07:00 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -w --table filter --delete INPUT --in-interface VMmaint --protocol udp --destination-port 53 --jump ACCEPT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
2016-03-18 14:07:00 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -w --table filter --delete INPUT --in-interface VMmaint --protocol tcp --destination-port 53 --jump ACCEPT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
2016-03-18 14:07:00 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -w --table filter --delete OUTPUT --out-interface VMmaint --protocol udp --destination-port 68 --jump ACCEPT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
2016-03-18 14:07:00 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -w --table filter --delete INPUT --in-interface VMmaint --protocol udp --destination-port 67 --jump ACCEPT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
2016-03-18 14:07:00 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -w --table filter --delete INPUT --in-interface VMmaint --protocol tcp --destination-port 67 --jump ACCEPT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).`

It seems there are some default configurations somewhere in libvirtd that is not interacting well with firewalld. I like to learn the right way of configuring this through libvirt without having to run any scripts separately.
morganyang1982

Posts: 2
Joined: 2016/03/18 13:50:52

Answer (score 0):

There might be a rogue firewalld process involved, similar to this: [firewalld errors when adding http](https://serverfault.com/questions/726505/firewalld-errors-when-adding-http/726520)

Try stopping the firewall, killing all remaining firewalld processes and starting it up again.

```
systemctl stop firewalld
pkill -f firewalld
systemctl start firewalld
```

On a more general note: It's perfectly valid to disable firewalld and roll your own firewall using a bash script or something like shorewall.

Comment: Thank you, it use to have firewalld turned off and use iptables only. But the latest update from CentOS7 requires that firewalld to be running for libvirtd to run.

Comment: so it's working now? if i was able to help you out, i'd appreciate it, it you would mark this as the correct answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately, its still not working. I'm going to dig around alittle more today, and if I don't come across any resolution, i'm ready to redesign the application to use bridged network vs NAT.

Comment: Hi marco, this seems to be a know centos issue, so I'm just going to work around it for now