# CentOS 7 - firewalld[8509]: ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED

Tags: centos, firewall, centos7, firewalld

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status firewalld -l
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-09-23 00:27:10 EDT; 2h 51min ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 8509 (firewalld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
           └─8509 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

Sep 23 00:27:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Sep 23 00:27:10 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Sep 23 03:01:26 localhost.localdomain firewalld[8509]: WARNING: '/usr/sbin/iptables-restore --wait=2 -n' failed: iptables-restore: line 2 failed
Sep 23 03:01:26 localhost.localdomain firewalld[8509]: ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED
Sep 23 03:01:32 localhost.localdomain firewalld[8509]: WARNING: '/usr/sbin/iptables-restore --wait=2 -n' failed: iptables-restore: line 2 failed
Sep 23 03:01:32 localhost.localdomain firewalld[8509]: ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED
```

I am getting the above error message. I tried Googling for solutions, but couldn't find a solution. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I found this simple trick to do the job, though I still do not know what caused this issue.

These three lines of cmd will solve the issue:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
pkill -f firewalld
systemctl start firewalld
```

Credit: [firewalld errors when adding http](https://serverfault.com/questions/726505/firewalld-errors-when-adding-http)